# <th>, <td> inconsistency with box-layout

Tags: html, css

I have used a standard CSS reset, then applied the following styles to table elements:

```
.ns-table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ns-tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.ns-th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.ns-td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

My problem is that `th` is adhering to the box-layout and rendering at `40px`. `td`, however, is rendering at `41px` and not adhering to `border-box`. Why are there inconsistencies across `th` and `td` when it comes to `box-sizing: border-box;` property?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Could we how these are nested in your html?

Comment: I found the issue—it is do do with `display: table-cell` not consistently rendering `box-sizing: border-box` consistently across browsers. How do I mark my own question as a duplicate?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! Flag your question as duplicate and include the article its a duplicate of and a mod will take care of the rest.

Comment: In this case you can choose "close" instead of "flag". You can also self-approve your own duplicate vote right after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS div with display:table-cell and box-sizing:border-box - width/height calculation inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531266/css-div-with-displaytable-cell-and-box-sizingborder-box-width-height-calcula)